# I cannot import a module and I don't know why Python: ImportError: Cannot import name X

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I'm having the following error when I try  to run a Flask app:

```
 File "/home/patterson/Documentos/CPFL/cpfl/computer.py", line 12, in <module>
        from cpfl.cpfl import sendmail
    ImportError: cannot import name 'sendmail'
```

sendmail is a function I'm trying to import from the cpfl.py module which is a flask app.
cpfl.py:

```
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
```

The structure of my project is as follows:

[image]

I have no idea why import does not work.
Could someone help-me?

Comment: Can you import functions from other files? Can you import another function from this file? Is there a function called `sendmail` in that file? What (if anything) have you done to try to debug this so far?

Comment: I think you could probably just do from cpfl.py import sendmail

Comment: @smarx Yes, I can import from other files. No I can't import any function from cpfl.py. Yes, there is a function called sendmail in that file.
The only thing I did was try to run the app. I do not understand what may be going wrong so I asked here.

Comment: I don't know if it is the colors on my screen but it seems that the folder `templates` is blue which means that you defined it as the root folder. I had a similar problem some weeks ago and setting the folder at the top as the Sources Root solved it. Have you tried to right-click on the CPFL folder and go to Mark Directory as -> Sources Root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `import cpfl` and then when you call the method you use `cpfl.sendmail`?

Comment: If this works, then another fix is presumably `from cpfl import sendmail`.

Comment: Wow! Why I didn't think in it before? It worked, thanks!